# R tm and wordcloud with cyrillic text

Tags: r, text-mining, cyrillic, word-cloud

I'm trying to create a wordcloud in R following some examples. As usual I encountered some problems with encoding, tried to fix them and did not succeed.

Here is my code:

```
library(tm)
library(wordcloud)
library(SnowballC)

articles <- Corpus (DirSource('tmp/'), readerControl = list(reader = readPlain,
                                                        language = "ru",
                                                        load = T))

articles <- tm_map(articles, iconv, 'cp1251', 'UTF-8')
articles <- tm_map(articles, stripWhitespace)
articles <- tm_map(articles, tolower)
articles <- tm_map(articles, removeNumbers)
articles <- tm_map(articles, removeWords, stopwords("russian"))
articles <- tm_map(articles, removePunctuation)
articles <- tm_map(articles, PlainTextDocument)


wordcloud(articles, random.order=F, max.words=80, 
          colors=brewer.pal(6,"Oranges"))
```

I don't get any errors, but the cloud seems to be in other kind of encoding - although there are cyrillic characters, there are also some others. 
[Here is the resulting wordcloud](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edu82.png).

How can I fix this?

Thank you in advance!

UPD. My input file is in UTF-8. I figured out first tm_map converts Windows-1251 into UTF-8, so I changed the input file to 1251. [But nothing changed much...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRSet.png)